# $\wedge^{2} \ (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}) = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, multilinear-algebra

I have to prove that $$\wedge^{2} \ (\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}) = 0$$ where $\wedge$ is the wedge product.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$, every element has finite order. On the other hand, you can also divide by any integer in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$. Use bilinearity.